# Updating Entity Framework Model after adding a field to a previous look up only table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, entity-framework

To better illustrate the problem :

I have a table called Action with key AID and I have a table called Requirement with RID.

Previously I had a lookup table that simply held an AID and an RID.

This was fine, Action had a navigation property Requirements and Requirement had a navigation property Actions.

I added a field called Weight to the lookup table called Requirement_Fulfillment.

I updated the model from database. I ran the custom tool.

The model doesn't show a table for Requirement_Fulfillment. The two tables (Action and Requirement) still see each other as simply navigation properties.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Stupid question perhaps, but are you sure you're refreshing from the right database?

Comment: Yeah, I should note I made other minor changes to some tables that were updated no problem. (i.e. Changed length of nvarchar on one table and added a field to another table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used to have a mapping, and now you have a new entity.

You'll probably have to delete the relationship between Action and Requirement in the designer. Then update your model from the database, and make sure the lookup table is checked in the `Tables` branch of the `Add` tab. Then you should have a new entity based on the lookup table, and the `Action` and `Requirement` entities will have a relationship with that entity (instead of having a direct mapping to each other).

If the lookup table doesn't show up in the update wizard, you might try manually deleting any reference to the table in the `.edmx` file.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Deleted relationship. Updated from database. On the Add screen, selected tables (note: the name of the look up table wasn't visible). Closed and saved model. Ran custom tool on the .tt entity class files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I always delete tables from my model, and then add them back in to get the latest updates from the DB; I think its the only reliable method (assuming you are using DB first). 'Update model from database' doesn't do what its name implies.

Comment: When you say delete tables, do you mean the ones associated with each other?

Comment: All of them, or just the ones that changed if you have kept track. Make a copy of your EDMX file just in case

Answer (score 0):

Try a refresh of the tables or simply delete tables from the designer and re-add them.